# Testing Gamelift in local, can only create 1 game session?

Tags: amazon-gamelift

I am testing our application in local, and it seems like i can only create 1 game session using Gamelift local.

so what i did is I run gamelift local

```
java -jar GameLiftLocal.jar -p 9080
```

run the custom gamelift server i wrote in C# and Unity
and use CLI to create game session

```
AWS gamelift create-game-session --endpoint-url http://localhost:9080 --maximum-player-session-count 2 --fleet-id fleet-123d
```

and first run, it succeed and creates the game session.
when I create another gamesession by issuing the same command above it results to

```
HTTP-Dispatcher - No available process.
```

Why is this? can we only create one Game Session in local?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make another game session, you need to run multiple game server processes.

GameLift can catch the game session's status by receiving Server-side API call from game server process.

I think this diagram can help you.:)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamelift/latest/developerguide/gamelift-sdk-server-api-interaction-vsd.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> Each server process should only host a single game session.
> ...
> When testing locally with GameLift Local, you can start multiple server processes. Each process will connect to GameLift Local.

Sounds like you need to run multiple instances of `GameLiftLocal`.
Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamelift/latest/developerguide/integration-testing-local.html